# Get Hidden Layers in PyTorch TransformerEncoder

Tags: python, pytorch, transformer, encoder

I am trying to access the hidden layers when using `TransformerEncoder` and `TransformerEncoderLayer`. I could not find anything like that in the source code for these classes.

I am not using hugging face but I know one can get `hidden_states` and `last_hidden_state`. I am looking for something similar.

Do you know how I can access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure which hidden layer you are looking for, but the [`TransformerEncoderLayer`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/transformer.py#L258) class simply has the different layers as attributes which can easily access (e.g. `self.linear1` or `self.self_attn`). The `TransformerEncoder` is simply a stack of `TransformerEncoderLayer` layers, which are stored in the `layer` attribute as a list. For each layer in the list you can then access the hidden layers as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. What I want to access (and cannot) is the output of these layers.

Comment: It depends a bit on how you are using these layer, but indeed it seems that you cannot get the output from the `TransformerEncoderLayer` from the `TransformerEncoder` directly as the forward pass only returns the final output without saving the intermediate results. What you could do is manually run the forward pass by looping over the different layers and pass the data through.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Can you please elaborate what you mean by "manually running the forward pass"?

Comment: You can loop through the list and for each of the encoders run the forward pass, which would look something like this: `for layer in self.layers: data = layer(input)`.